# Android Custom Keyboard with short video length

Tags: android, android-layout, android-keypad

Is there any possibility to create a custom keyboard with some videos of just 5 to 10 seconds.please help me.Below image is my requirement

[image]

Comment: Do you need to put actual video files or GIFs?

Comment: my first preference to put video files if it not possible gif files.

Comment: Why you want a custom keyboard for that? or your requirement is only to show video grid view for video selection like provided view?

Comment: i want that keyboard to be used in other apps

Comment: A keyboard is just an app.  So yes, you can do it.  Just create a keyboard app (following any of the numerous tutorials) and make its onCreateInputView return a view with a bunch of videos.  Now I have no idea how useful you could make it-  actually inserting the videos into the app you're typing into would not be possible.